# Redirecionamento após login no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu criei um novo tipo de usuário com a função de comprador no wordpress sempre que um novo usuário é registrado o 
mesmo recebe dois links, um para mudar a senha e outro que direciona para uma tela de login, estou com problema nesta parte, a 
cada usuário registrado com a função de comprador o Wordpress envia esses links, o de login quando clica direciona para tela de login 
e quando é feito o login ele redireciona para o painel de assinante onde altera o perfil e tal, só que essa permissão de comprador deve ser 
redirecionado para uma URL específico qual é o arquivo responsável pelo envio desse link para que eu possa mudar 
o URL de redirecionamento, ou há outra solução? como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Henrique quer codar isso ? ou usar um plugin ?

Comment: Não quero usar plugin não, estava usando um e deu problema, prefiro fazer na unha mesmo...haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que possa funcionar tem que mandar na URL do email um parâmetro como URL para o login exemplo: 
http://www.henrique.com.br/wp-login?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fjamil%2Fconsulta%2F

Lembre-se de colocar pelo a URL [encoded](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php). E coloque esse código no functions.php do seu tema atual.

```
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_after_login');
function redirect_after_login()
{
    global $redirect_to;
    if   (isset($_GET['url']))
    {
        $redirect_to =   $_GET['url'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#loginform").on('submit', function() {
            var input_data = $('#loginform').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php','login_post'); ?>",
                data: input_data,
                success: function(msg) {
                    var reg1 = /login_error/g;
                    if (reg1.test(msg)) {
                         $('#message').html("Usuário ou senha incorretos.");
                    } else {
                        window.location = "http://url-que-voce-deseja-enviar-o-usuario.com.br";
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```